# Html errors in Internet explorer 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer

On this website: http://fa-aft6157.org/ , when viewed in IE8, when you hover the mouse over the links on the left they appear at the top of the page. How can this be fixed in the HTML code?

Comment: Most likely some mistakes in the positioning of your submenu in your css file.

Comment: Just pointers who are going to help:
1. Left sidebar is dynamically generated via Javascript = see menu_com.js
2. The menu works perfectly using IE8 compatibility view mode
3. It's indeed an CSS positioning issue and it's god awfully hard to fix since the Developer Tools as the source view doesn't show dynamically generated content

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you position an element absolutely with css, the element is positioned relative to the closest parent that has position defined.

I think your problem has to do with the fact that all of your menu DIVs are direct children of BODY. You may have better luck placing your menu DIVs inside a parent DIV that has position defined.